# Link to reputation link is always to weeks whatever "week / month / year / all time" you choose in Users - reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-leagues

In the [Users > reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation) page there is a [weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/stackoverflow) link pointing to "week" league.

What happens is that the link doesn't update to month/quarter/year/all time whenever you click in the tabs of "month/quarter/year/all time".

> [image]
>
> [image]

For example, when filtering:

- **month**, the link below is to
  https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month&search=fedorqui
- **year**, the link below is the same:
  https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year&search=fedorqui

Shouldn't it update to the corresponding page link?

Comment: You mean the link in the address bar?

Comment: @AmalMurali I just added an image. It is the link below the users list.

Comment: `status-repro`..

Comment: It's just *one link*. Since there is no one overview page for the SO leagues, it links to one of the league pages instead.